# fadeOut a content using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

How can i fadeOut a div using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You realise jQuery has [a website](http://jquery.com/) with [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page), right?

And if you were to look at that documentation, you'd come across [the answer](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut).

```
$("#theIDofYourDivTag").fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: But it is not working in jquery-1.3.2-min.js
Any idea????

Comment: I'd suggest that the problem is more likely in your code or environment and not in jquery.

Comment: @Karthik - Use Firebug. It debugs Javascript in Firefox. And it has a lot more context to the actual problem than we do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut("slow");
```